# Nginx error_page directive : Can I pass an argument?

Tags: nginx, parameter-passing, config

I want to pass an argument when I use **'error_page'** directive in **Nginx** config file, like below.

I'd made **'err.html'** to process the response status code using JavaScript. But below does not work at all.

```
error_page     
400 401 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 = /err.html?$status;
```

Is there any other way to pass the response status code(or other arguments) when I use 'error_page' directive?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page "A uri value can contain variables."

Answer (score 2):

(I rewrote this answer)

The problem was caused by my confusion on the internal redirection and the external redirection. Below works well. (assume that 'err.php' handles the query string properly)

```
error_page  400 401 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 /err.php?$status;
```

If I want client-side JavaScript to handle the response status code(passed through the query string), I should try another way, as Satys said. And I could find a way.

```
error_page  400 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 @err;

location @err {
    rewrite ^.*$ /err.html?$status redirect;
}
```

Thank you for your advise, Satys.

Comment: This configuration results in status code 302 and a location header which the browser follows to a perfectly valid 200 page, i.e. your error page. So even when the original status code is preserved in the query parameter a crawler would see a perfectly valid page and is going to index it. Just try `curl -v https://example.com` to see the status.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a wrong concept. On error, using error_page, nginx does not return url back but instead does an internal redirection, and sends and alternate response.

In order to achieve this, currently I can think of two ways,

1. **multiple error_pages** for different error codes, and pre-code the
   javascript into those pages.

   ```
   error_page 404 err404.html;

   error_page 403 err403.html;
   ...
   ```

This seems little lengthy.

2. Internally **redirect to some custom location** block and add a header
   in the response.

error_page 404 405 ... /custom_error$status;

```
location ~ /custom_error(.*) {
   add_header Error-Code $1;
   try_files /err.html.html 404;
}
```

P.S. please checkout for syntax errors, above code is not tested.